# How to make navigation arrow more conspicuous when using Quarto to make revealjs slides

Tags: r, r-markdown, reveal.js, quarto

How do I adjust the navigation arrows in revealjs when using Quarto in vertical navigation. The down arrow can be easily hidden by slide content. I would like to increase the size, change the color or animate the navigation arrow.

My sample code is below any help is appreciated.

```
---
format:
  revealjs:
    controls: true
    navigation-mode: vertical
    self-contained: true
---


#  Adjust Navigation Arrows

##  

-   How do I format the down arrow to navigate to this slide so it is more noticeable such as increasing size, changing color or animating it?
```

Comment: That's too many questions to answer in one question : )

Comment: Ha! I am hoping they are somewhat related but I have no clue...

Comment: I will break them up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set css rules for `.navigate-up` and `.navigate-down` classes.

```
---
format:
  revealjs:
    controls: true
    navigation-mode: vertical
    self-contained: true
    css: styles.css
---

#  Adjust Navigation Arrows

##  

-   How do I format the down arrow to navigate to this slide so it is more noticeable such as increasing size, changing color or animating it?
```

**styles.css**

```
.navigate-up .controls-arrow,
.navigate-down .controls-arrow {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

This will style both the up and down navigation buttons.

---

[image: Styling navigation button in Vertical mode]

---

If you only want to style the down arrow button, just remove the `.navigate-down .controls-arrow` css selector.

```
.navigate-down .controls-arrow {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```